# Why should anyone care about computing the Hausdorff Dimension?

Tags: dimension-theory-analysis

I am trying to justify an thesis/investigation that will (hopefully) lead to a formula for computing a particular class of Cantor-like sets. The question that I have not satisfactorily answered, according to my department chair, is 'Why should anyone care about computing the Hausdorff Dimension?'

Comment: I'm by no means an expert but I get the feeling that Hausdorff Dimension helps one to understand complex geometric figures which have all sorts of applications i.e. crystallography, material science etc.

Comment: I think of Hausdorff dimensions as a scale (indexed by all real numbers up to the dimension of the ambient space) of strictly increasing notions of "measure zero" that can be used to classify (in one way) the size of measure zero sets (which occur all over the place in real analysis).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one, it gives an invariant which helps us distinguish sets which are otherwise rather difficult to tell apart, and in a way which is reflected in actual, interesting properties of the sets.

On the other hand, there are many situations in which the Hasdorff dimension of a set controls analytical properties of solutions of certain differential equations and that sort of thing —imagine you are trying to solve a PDE on an open set with a very complicated boundary, for example (and no, this is not done out of pure pleasure: «real life» problems lead to to such monstruosities). This is quite useful when it is needed!

Answer (score 0):

I may be shunned by real mathematicians for this but I think it can provide some detail about "how long a coastline is" since they exhibit fractal behaviour. The length keeps getting longer when you measure more closely.

Numberphile did a good video on it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7dcDuVyzb8Y

Answer (score 0):

For instance, there are various results about Kleinian groups and the hausdorf dimension of their limit sets

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleinian_group